# Is it possible to get a subflow name inside one of its functions on Node-RED?

Tags: node-red

I know we can get both a node name and id with `node.name` and `node.id` using a function on Node-RED. However, when I create a subflow sometimes the name of the subflow would be a useful information to have. I've tried getting it as an environment variable with `env.get('Name')` but it doesn't work. Is there any way of getting a subflow name from within it? Or the only solution is to create a new field where I repeat the name and get it as an environment variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access the subflow name directly.

As you suggest, the workaround is to add a custom subflow property and use that instead.